# "Could not create java virtual machine" error while trying to open MyEclipse Enterprise Workbench

Tags: java, ide, myeclipse

I am using **MyEclipse Enterprise Workbench 5.1.0 GA** and when I open it I get the error ***"could not create java virtual machine"***. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Look in the log file.  There should be something in there that gives more information.

Comment: Try the latest release, 2013 (aka 11). I can't remember if 5.1 came with Java but the latest release has everything needed, including Java. Your license applies to all releases for the period it's valid.